# React app will give 404 on refreshing page in prod, but not in dev

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app, and I have an issue with 404 in my navigation, if I try to refresh a page that is not the root page, it will give me a 404.

Thing is it only happens to me on production and not on dev.

In dev environment, I use `npm start`, on prod environment, I use `serve build`.

This make debug more complicated, as I lose the hot-reload option for debugging. I must compile my docker image each time I make a change.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>

            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/premiere-connexion" component={FirstLoginLayout}/>
                {(user.state === "1" && window.location.pathname === "/premiere-connexion") &&
                <Redirect to="/premiere-connexion"/>}
                <PrivateRoute path="/bo" component={BackOfficeLayout} profiles={["ADMIN"]}/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Customer}/>
                <Redirect to="/"/>
            </Switch>
            }
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Any Idea how should I reproduce it in local ?

Comment: Have you used router?

Comment: Is your app inside a sub-directory of your webpage (https://example.com/subdirectory)?

Comment: @iamrajshah I add a bit of code, I use BrowserRouter

Comment: @Rallen nop, I use subdomains, and Caddy

Comment: If you are using [Zeit's serve](https://github.com/zeit/serve) to serve the build folder, you might have to tell it to redirect all requests to the index.html file, since otherwise, `serve` will expect your deep links are folders in the build folder.  Check out the [Configuration section](https://github.com/zeit/serve#configuration) on `serve`'s documentation. There's a `rewrite` option that could be useful

Comment: Can you paste some component code?? I mean to say life-cycle hooks methods?

Comment: @hbentlov yes, I am using it. I think I use Create React App (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). Thus, I can't see any mention in the code to http.createServer method

Comment: @iamrajshah off course, but I'm a bit new to React, so I will need a bit more information about life-cycle hooks methods. Can you give me an example of a method name ?

Comment: @hbentlov I'm not sure in which folder shoud I put the serve.json? I'm building the project with  `npm run build`

Comment: @hbentlov I've added serve.yml to public/ folder, and it works like a charm. Please put it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With @hbentlov recommendations, I solved this issue creating a file `serve.json` in the `public/` folder, with this content:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here as I hade the same problem; when you call React Router addresses directly you get a 404 error when you run react on a docker.

The solution is to tell your nginx that send non existing urls to index.html (and it is pretty much easy)

You need to make a `nginx.conf` file (in my case next to Dockerfile) and copy it in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf inside your container.

Here is the `nginx.conf`

```
# auto detects a good number of processes to run
worker_processes auto;

#Provides the configuration file context in which the directives that affect connection processing are specified.
events {
    # Sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.
    worker_connections 8000;
    # Tells the worker to accept multiple connections at a time
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    # what times to include
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # what is the default one
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Sets the path, format, and configuration for a buffered log write
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen 80;
        # save logs here
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;

        # where the root here
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # what file to server as index
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
          expires 1M;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Javascript and CSS files
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

**That is how you apply it** : add `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in your Dockerfile.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this :

```
# build environment
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build


# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
# Nginx configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The line   `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` tells nginx to fall back to index.html

Hope it helps others that end-up here

Answer (score 0):

if using netlify hosting then you can try creating file _redirects and add the 1 line code

/*    /index.html   200

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. This answer is not a proper answer for the original question. Please, consider removing it as you could get downvoted.